# sqlloader does not upload the data

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

for instance I have this file downloaded from wikipedia

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2018/2018-04/pageviews-20180407-130000.gz

After download and unzip I am trying to load into a table using sqlloader but I am failing.   Can you help me ?

```
    LOAD 
 INFILE D:\pageviews\year=2016\month=06\*
 INTO TABLE teste
skip 1
fields terminated BY WHITESPACE,OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Example of the file

```
aa File:Cash_payment_timeline_on_foreclosures.jpg 1 0
aa Main_Page 4 0
aa Special:AllPages 1 0
aa Special:ListUsers 1 0
aa Special:SpecialPages 1 0
aa User:å°èº 1 0
aa.m.b Main_Page 1 0
ab ÐÐºÐ°Ñ‚ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð°:User_sk 1 0
ab Ð‘ÑƒÑ€ÑÐ° 1 0
ab Ð“Ð°Ð¹_Ð®Ð»Ð¸Ð¹_Ð¦ÐµÐ·Ð°Ñ€ÑŒ 1 0
ab Ð˜ÐµÑÑƒÐ°_ÒšÑŒÑ‹Ñ€ÑÑ‚Ð° 1 0
ab Ð˜Ñ…Ð°Ð´Ð¾Ñƒ_Ð°Ð´Ð°ÒŸÑŒÐ° 3 0
ab Ð£Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÑÐ¼_Ð¨ÐµÐºÑÐ¿Ð¸Ñ€ 1 0
ab Ð¤Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ñ†Ð¸Ð° 1 0
```

the column separator are white spaces and the table  can be `c1 char 4000,  c2 char 4000, c3 char 4000,  c4 c 4000`   just to test the first load.   the table are  always 4 columns

Comment: I'm not going to download that file, but - if you could post a few sample rows from it, it would help us help you. From what I see now, control file is incomplete. Besides, we don't have table description (the one you're trying to put that file into). Shortly, put some more effort into asking a question.

Comment: Done thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thank you for posting additional info.

Test table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (c1 varchar2(4000), c2 varchar2(4000), c3 varchar2(4000), c4 varchar2(4000));

Table created.
```

Control file (I included sample data into it, for simplicity):

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by whitespace
trailing nullcols
(
c1,
c2,
c3,
c4
)

begindata
aa File:Cash_payment_timeline_on_foreclosures.jpg 1 0
aa Main_Page 4 0
aa Special:AllPages 1 0
aa Special:ListUsers 1 0
aa Special:SpecialPages 1 0
aa User:å°èº 1 0
aa.m.b Main_Page 1 0
ab ÐÐºÐ°Ñ‚ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ñ€Ð¸Ð°:User_sk 1 0
ab Ð‘ÑƒÑ€ÑÐ° 1 0
ab Ð“Ð°Ð¹_Ð®Ð»Ð¸Ð¹_Ð¦ÐµÐ·Ð°Ñ€ÑŒ 1 0
ab Ð˜ÐµÑÑƒÐ°_ÒšÑŒÑ‹Ñ€ÑÑ‚Ð° 1 0
ab Ð˜Ñ…Ð°Ð´Ð¾Ñƒ_Ð°Ð´Ð°ÒŸÑŒÐ° 3 0
ab Ð£Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÑÐ¼_Ð¨ÐµÐºÑÐ¿Ð¸Ñ€ 1 0
ab Ð¤Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ñ†Ð¸Ð° 1 0
```

Loading session:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@xe control=test03.ctl log=test03.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Ned Kol 26 23:43:17 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 13
Commit point reached - logical record count 14

SQL>
```

Result:

```
SQL> col c1 format a7
SQL> col c2 format a60
SQL> col c3 format a2
SQL> col c4 format a2
SQL>
SQL> select * From test;

C1      C2                                                           C3 C4
------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -- --
aa      File:Cash_payment_timeline_on_foreclosures.jpg               1  0
aa      Main_Page                                                    4  0
aa      Special:AllPages                                             1  0
aa      Special:ListUsers                                            1  0
aa      Special:SpecialPages                                         1  0
aa      User:├ą┬░├Ę┬║                                                1  0
aa.m.b  Main_Page                                                    1  0
ab      ├É├É┬║├É┬░├ĹÔÇÜ├É┬Á├É┬│├É┬ż├ĹÔéČ├É┬Ş├É┬░:User_sk             1  0
ab      ├ÉÔÇś├ĹĂĺ├ĹÔéČ├Ĺ├É┬░                                         1  0
ab      ├ÉÔÇť├É┬░├É┬╣_├É┬«├É┬╗├É┬Ş├É┬╣_├É┬Ž├É┬Á├É┬Ě├É┬░├ĹÔéČ├Ĺ┼ĺ     1  0
ab      ├É╦ť├É┬Á├Ĺ├ĹĂĺ├É┬░_├ĺ┼í├Ĺ┼ĺ├ĹÔÇ╣├ĹÔéČ├Ĺ├ĹÔÇÜ├É┬░             1  0
ab      ├É╦ť├ĹÔÇŽ├É┬░├É┬┤├É┬ż├ĹĂĺ_├É┬░├É┬┤├É┬░├ĺ┼Ş├Ĺ┼ĺ├É┬░           3  0
ab      ├É┬ú├É┬Ş├É┬╗├Ĺ┼ĺ├Ĺ├É┬╝_├É┬Ę├É┬Á├É┬║├Ĺ├É┬┐├É┬Ş├ĹÔéČ           1  0
ab      ├É┬Ą├ĹÔéČ├É┬░├É┬Ż├ĹÔÇá├É┬Ş├É┬░                               1  0

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Most of it looks like *garbage* to me, but reason might be codepage difference. Hopefully, you'll see something *smarter* than that, once you manage to load data. Good luck!

Comment: is it the   same in  windows using sqldevloper ?   I mean I guess I just need load data 
infile *
replace
into table test
fields terminated by whitespace
trailing nullcols
(
c1,
c2,
c3,
c4
) .  Is that corretc ?

Comment: SQL Loader is to be run at the operating system command prompt, just like I did. I don't know whether it works from SQL Developer.

Comment: got it :)   Thanks for the help I am  oracle very novice